# Sorting Records by size of an array in MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

Here is my sample MongoDB collection, I need a list of all the records by ascending order of number of subjects student enrolled.

The corresponding mysql query will be

```
SELECT name, COUNT(subject_code) AS NUM FROM table_name ORDER BY NUM ASC
```

Please help me to find a MongoDb query to do the same:

```
{
    ["name"]=> string(5) "David"   
    ["subject_code"]=> array(5) {
        [0]=> int(101)
        [1]=> int(111)
        [2]=> int(121)
        [3]=> int(123)
        [4]=> int(53)
    }
}
```

Comment: "*This question does not show any research effort,...*" Please spend 10 minutes to read about [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) and you will be able to answer the question yourself: project size of the array, and then sort the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the already available answers. Those are not really helpful. Hope this answer will be helpful.

Suppose you have the following documents

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "david", subject_code: [ 101, 111, 121 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "joe", subject_code: [ 131 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "sam", subject_code: [ ] }
```

This query will list the length of list as field len

```
db.collname.aggregate([{ $project: { name: 1, len: { $size: "$subject_code" }}}])
```

Output will be

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "david", len: 3 }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "joe", len: 1 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "sam", len: 0 }
```

Now things are easy.. use a sort function on the output (on field "len")

```
db.collname.aggregate( 
[
    {$project: {"name": 1, "nump": { $size: { "$ifNull": ["$subject_code", []] }}}},
    {$sort: {nump: -1}} 
])
```

And this is your complete query. It will sort by the field nump and uses [] emply list if the subject_code field is of some other type or Null